# Scatter 3D using plotty

Tags: python

I want to change the name of x to pc1, y to pc2, z to pc3
I used that code

```
fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x =components_pca[:,0],y =components_pca[:,1], z =components_pca[:,2],  color=products)                         
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Plotly you can use:

```
fig.update_layout(scene = dict(
                    xaxis_title='x-axis title',
                    yaxis_title='y-axis title',
                    zaxis_title='z-axis title'))
```

...before your `fig.show()`. For more info, see their [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/3d-axes/).